# Loop though table adapter methods checking if scalar

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Currently I have about 30 table adapters that all have a query "InsertAndReturnId". Which is a  insert query that returns the last inserted id. To get this to work I have to set the execute mode of the query to Scalar (in visual studios Dataset Designer).

The problem is when I edit or save that query it will reset the execute mode back to non-query and sometimes I forget to change it back.

It's a real pain as they both return a int value (and most of this code just casts the return value to an int)

I've looked at what is generated by Visual Studio and it looks like depends on the execute property it will add:

```
returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Or

```
   int returnValue = this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I would rather no go though each use of these methods and add a check. Or add a check condition for each table adapter.

Is it possible to loop though (during compiling or at run time) table adapters generated by visual studio and check if they execute as a scalar or non query?

Something like:

```
foreach(var tableAdapterMethod in tableAdapterMethods)
{
    if(tableAdapterMethod.Name == "InsertAndReturnId")
    {
       if(tableAdapterMethod.ExecuteType != "Scalar")
       {
            // throw warning and stop further execution.
        }
     }
 }
```